# Android equivalent to iphone indexed UITableView

Tags: iphone, android

I am porting an iPhone app over to the Android platform. One of the views has a very large list of data and on the iPhone app, there's a scrollbar of sorts on the right hand side that displays the letters of the alphabet and allows the user to quickly scroll through the list this way. I am having trouble finding such functionality in Android. Is there a simple way to implement this?

Comment: Not sure if you still need it, but i have created a android library for that. Check this out [UITableView for Android](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview)

Comment: Does it dequeue? Does it have multiple sections? Does it keep the current section's header at the top of the visible view? (Bumping out the previous header if need be.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is implemented through [AlphabetIndexer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.html), though I have not tried it personally.

Answer (score 1):

The Android way to do this is to make the list filterable using the keyboard, like a Blackberry. You should do it this way to fit in with the platform experience.

To implement this, you call the `setTextFilterEnabled(boolean textFilterEnabled)` method on your list view. See example below:

```
myListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

For a complete example, see [Hello, ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).

---

If you can't use that, then you can use the fast scrolling like seen in the Contacts application. This is not a public API yet, but you can implement it from the Contacts source code at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts
.

Comment: I enabled this and it takes an extremely long time for the internal filtering to work and filter the results given the volume of data. I am implementing a different kind of filter at the client's request, but I really wanted to be able to quickly scroll through the list by the first letter of each item like you can in large table views on the iPhone.

Comment: I see. What you need then is the FastScrollView, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Right side Alphabet indexer with working sources
http://hello-android.blogspot.com/2010/11/sideindex-for-android.html