# iPhone section index for android?

Tags: android

I need some examples or tutorial, how to implement iPhone side index for Android.

[image]

I read already [this topic (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201962/android-equivalent-to-iphone-indexed-uitableview)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201962/android-equivalent-to-iphone-indexed-uitableview) and I'm trying AlphabetIndexer, but:

- How do I create it properl at all?
- How can be AlphabetIndexer displayed?!
- Is an extra layout schema for indexed lists already defined?

**UPD:**

If you downvote the topic, could you at least argue, why.

Thank you

Mur

Comment: I'm just going to say you shouldnt emulate one UI paradigm in another phone, iPhone looks and feels the way it does and android is diferent, you should "think in Android", and not try to do a iPhone app for android.

Comment: 1. What if client wants to have some iPhone-things he likes?! 2. And what is Alphabet-Indexer for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, that I haven't reinvented the wheel.

I wrote a tutorial for all.

http://hello-android.blogspot.com/2010/11/sideindex-for-android.html

Comment: i give you a message in the above link,because it have some mistakes,could you modify it?

Comment: sorry, the blog is pretty new, so I haven't seen comments from you. I've added my sources, you'll find the link at the end of the page. And thank you for you comment