# Designing View Similar to the UITableView In Android

Tags: android, view, tableview

I am developing an android application where I want a table view such as UITableView in iPhone. Has any one tried before. I checked here their are many requirement for similar but seems no one tried before. Please any one has solution on this give to me.

Thank You.

Comment: Please pay attention to formatting when posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one first: [Android equivalent to iphone indexed UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201962/android-equivalent-to-iphone-indexed-uitableview/1202696#1202696)

Or this one: http://blogingtutorials.blogspot.com/2010/12/iphone-uitable-view-in-android.html (I haven't checked it yet, but its screenshot is OK).

Comment: Hello,

       I checked screen shot but this not what I want.
May be am not make clear in question let me try it again.
IF you check IPhone settings menu you will see Table view that what I want.
Like a row will have textview & Edittext as a single group....

Also I didn't checked source code for your link but I will check it & see if I can do something with it.

Thank You for your reply...

Comment: The download link at 'iphone-uitable-view-in-android' is broken, and someone in the comments mirrored the source behind a paywall. I'd steer clear and use your first suggestion instead.