# How to create Address Book in Android like in iPhone?

Tags: android, addressbook

I have a application which user details in a list format, for that I have used dynamic TableLayout. What I want is to create a Address Book like it comes in iPhone which contains a columns of alphabets so on pressing any of the alphabets the table sets the name starting with that alphabets at top of the table.

I have seen such thing in Android also in Samsung Galaxy Ace Phone.But I don't understand how to use it.

Please Help Me..

Comment: Are you referring to list section headers?

Comment: No I have used dynamic TableLayout in Table I want to create such functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're thinking of a `ListView` with an `AlphabetIndexer`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201962/android-equivalent-to-iphone-indexed-uitableview).